# Unix STREAMS to Linux Sockets

Tags: linux, sockets, unix, stream

I am in a fix here I have hit a road block compiling decades old c++ code with stropts.h header not to be found on Linux. On googling I found that Unix Streams are not implemented on Linux and the LiS Linux streams ported is old and I am restricted to use 3rd party. However, I know these can be converted to Sockets.
My question is, can some one point me to a tutorial or guide me as to how this is done?

Appreciate your help.

Regards.

Comment: I think it depends how STREAMS were being used. In old System V, STREAMS are used for everything from pipes (the `pipe()` system call uses STREAMS under the hood), tty drivers (including pseudo ttys `/dev/pts`), network sockets, and custom modules!